# How to configure genesis_config for pre defined functional pallets?

Tags: genesis, pallet-treasury, pallet-collective

Substrate has provided some pre-defined functional pallets. We need to configure these pallet in our custom runtime in order to use them.

Some of these pallets like [pallet_treasury](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_treasury/index.html), [pallet_collective](https://docs.rs/pallet-collective/latest/pallet_collective/) requires some changes to genesis config. If any one can please share some resource that explains the nitty-gritty of these configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Config`s are some parameters which don't touch the storage. You can configure them in the runtime.

Configure the pallet-balances.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8cfe326e4e33c5077fc67f197d6a13dd871881c7/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L435-L445

---

`GenesisConfig`s are some data that you want to set into the genesis state. You can configure them in the chain spec.

Setup the pallet-balances genesis state.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8cfe326e4e33c5077fc67f197d6a13dd871881c7/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L299-L301